# running python script with simplecv from headless raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I have a raspberry pi. Raspbian Jessie with simplecv installed and working. If I connect a monitor to it I can run a python program.

```
from SimpleCV import *

cam = Camera()
display = Display((800,600))
cam.getImage()
```

I can run this when I connect a monitor and mouse and keyboard to my raspberry pi. But when I SSH in to my raspberry pi and run the script it gives me an error: `error: Unable to open a console terminal`

So I found that you can use `simplecv --headless` to use simplecv without a monitor. But I would like to do this in my pyhton script.

So is there a way to open simplecv headless in my python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual code behind the argument is this:

```
if flag in ['--headless', 'headless']:
    # set SDL to use the dummy NULL video driver,
    #   so it doesn't need a windowing system.
    os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy"
```

So you will need to set the SDL_VIDEODRIVER environment variable in your script.

Source: https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV/blob/6c4d61b6d1d9d856b471910107cad0838954d2b2/SimpleCV/Shell/Shell.py

Comment: You mean I would need to put os.environ[SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy". In my code?